# Is SLF4J thread-safe?

Tags: java, logging, thread-safety, slf4j, thread-local

I might have a `Dog` class that has a single instance shared across multiple threads. I plan on using SLF4J for all logging:

```
public class Dog {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Dog.class);

    // ...etc.
}
```

Is my `logger` instance thread safe? Why/why not?

Answer (score 48):

Certainly, everyone *assumes* that a `Logger` is going to be thread-safe.  And (IMO) it is a *reasonable* working assumption.  However, you would need to look at the code / javadocs of the implementation classes behind the facade to be **absolutely** sure.

I found the following statements on thread safety for various mainstream implementations:

- [Log4j 1.2 is thread-safe](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a1.7)
- [java.util.logging.Logger is thread-safe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) (search for "multi-thread safe")
- [Logback is thread-safe](http://logback.10977.n7.nabble.com/logback-and-thread-safety-td509.html)

(Obviously, these are statements that the respective code is *designed* to thread-safe.  There can always be bugs.  For example, were *at the time of writing* a couple of open thread-safety bugs in [the Log4j 2 tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20LOG4J2%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20text%20%7E%20%22thread%20safe%22), though it doesn't seem like those bugs would directly affect *your* example code.)

In fact, it is not possible to guarantee that a `Logger` will always be thread-safe.  Someone could implement their own slf4j compatible logging classes.  Such an implementation could be non-thread-safe, by accident or by design.  If it was, then the `Logger` exposed via the slf4j facade would also be non-thread-safe.