# Can I use static LOGGER object in fixedThreadPool?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, threadpool, slf4j

There is a spring-mvc web project. If the user does something important, the application must record log and send a message to the user's email in the service layer (btw, the user will do many important things). The code like below:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageServiceImpl.class);

private static final ExecutorService fixedThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

fixedThreadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (emailParams != null && EmailUtil.sendEmail(emailParams)) {
            LOGGER.info("send email succeed");
        } else {
            LOGGER.warn("send email failed");
        }
    }
});
```

There is two question I have met:

1. Can I use static LOGGER object in fixedThreadPool?

   If I use static logger object in fixedThreadPool, what will happen? Deadlock? Race condition? or nothing?
2. Should I define the fixedThreadPool static or not static?

   In my opinion:

   if fixedThreadPool is static and I don't invoke its shutdown(), so it will exist util web project is shutdown.

   if fixedThreadPool is `not` static and every request may produce one fixedThreadPool. Finally, this web project will have many useless fixedThreadPool, may produce Out-Of-Memery.

Comment: What kind of logger? Why have you omitted the imports from your code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the logging framework implementation. Most of the implementations are thread-safe however they can also be blocking. Log4j is thread-safe.

See [Is SLF4J thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543642/is-slf4j-thread-safe).

Comment: my project use slf4j + log4j

Comment: you are right, the first question is reduplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543642/is-slf4j-thread-safe . I have marked it. what about the second question ? Can you help me?

Comment: `static` code is generaly harder to test and should be discouraged because of it e.g. how would you write a test for `shutdown()` being called during JVM shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use `org.slf4j.Logger` right? SLF4j provides only an interface for a logger. So like @kdowbecki said it depends on which logger implementation you are using. For example `java.util.logging.Logger` is thread safe...

From the JavaDocs:

> All methods on Logger are multi-thread safe.

Here is a post that lists some examples:
[Is SLF4J thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543642/is-slf4j-thread-safe)